# Как вместе с номером и названием урока вывести и его Домашнее задание?

Tags: python, api, асинхронность

Всем доброго времени суток! :)
У меня возникла проблема! Мне нужно получить с помощью библиотеки [NetSchoolAPI](https://netschoolapi.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/) домашнее задание урока с электронного журнала и вывести их.

**Вот такой код у меня получился:**

```
import asyncio
from netschoolapi import NetSchoolAPI


async def main():
    # Создаём клиент. Через него мы будем обращаться
    # к АПИ электронного дневника
    ns = NetSchoolAPI('https://net-school.cap.ru/')

    # Логинимся в "Сетевой город"
    await ns.login(
        '',  # Логин ученика
        '',  # Пароль ученика
        511,  # id Школы
    )

    info = await ns.diary()
    lessons_list = info.schedule[0].lessons
    result = []
    for data in lessons_list:
        result.append(str(data.number) + ' урок: ' + data.subject + ' - ДЗ: ' + str(
            info.schedule[0].lessons[int(data.number)].assignments[
                0].content))  # Последняя строчка отвечает за вывод Домашнего Задания у каждого предмета
    schedule = '\n'.join(result)
    print(schedule)
    await ns.logout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Если вместо `int(data.number)` в `str(info.schedule[0].lessons[int(data.number)].assignments[0].content)` - подставить номер предмета, то мы получим вывод номера урока, его название и ДЗ но только этого предмета (что логично).

**Вот наглядный пример:**

```
1 урок: Разговоры о важном - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65
2 урок: Литература - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65 
3 урок: Информатика - ДЗ: &14 чит, №7 стр 65 
4 урок: История - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65 
5 урок: Алгебра и начала математического анализа - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65 
6 урок: Химия - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65 
7 урок: Обществознание - ДЗ: &14 чит , №7 стр 65
```

**Вот так это выглядит на официальном сайте, откуда и парсим данные:**
[image: Официальный сайт:]